# Cassandra point in time restore

Tags: cassandra, restore

I use Cassandra 3.11.4 and I want to restore a backup to a specific point in time , I changed  `commitlog_archiving.properties` file as follows:

```
archive_command=cp %path /cassandra/commitlog_archiving/%name
restore_command=/bin/cp -f %from %to
restore_directories=/cassandra/restore/
restore_point_in_time=2020:01:22 10:44:00
```

To restore I load the most recent snapshot and  copy corresponding commitlogs  (commitlogs produced after snapshot ) into `restore_directories`, and then restart cassandra, but unfortunately it doesn't work and it seems that it replays all the records even after the `restore_point_in_time`

Comment: Is  your time in GMT? Have you seen this article: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001593706-Manual-Backup-and-Restore-with-Point-in-time-and-table-level-restore- ?

Comment: Yes, I have read that article and I have set time in GMT

Comment: @kmhmd "it replays all the records even after the `restore_point_in_time`" are you able to identify upto which point?